# Google Apps Script - Spreadsheet.setActiveSheet not recognized when permission is not allow editing

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions

I'm observing current behavior is that this `onOpen` trigger in Google Apps Script on a Sheet is only setting the active sheet if the user has can edit permissions.

```
function setAppropriateMonthWorkbookBasedOnDate() {
  currentSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var dateObject = new Date()
  monthName = Utilities.formatDate(dateObject, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMMMM")
  targetWorksheet = currentSpreadSheet.getSheetByName(monthName)
  currentSpreadSheet.setActiveSheet(targetWorksheet);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  setAppropriateMonthWorkbookBasedOnDate();
}
```

I switched the user's permission to either can comment or can view and the `setActiveSheet` call seems to no longer work.

I'm struggling to see anything in those code that would be considered "editing."  The only modification action I see is the call to `setActiveSheet`.

This has been tested on two different sheets now: 1) my production sheet and 2) a prove-it throw away Sheet.

Thoughts on what might be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers only run when the user has edit privileges:

> onOpen(e) runs when a user opens a spreadsheet, document, or form that
>   he or she has permission to edit.

See full details here:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that reading the reference material.  It would be nice if it ran on other permission levels too like even "Can Comment".  I would think that my use case is not all that unusual.  There may be a need to focus the area of the spreadsheet you can view based on information determined `onOpen`.